# Can I skip assignment statement in a for loop for C#?

Tags: c#, for-loop

Is it possible to **skip the initialization statement** in a for loop for C# If I already have a variable with assigned value (and obviously want to use that variable as a counter in my loop)?

```cs
var i = 5; //already assigned the value that I want to use in a for loop

for(i<10; i++) //Compiler error
{
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can omit the initialization section, but you can't omit the semicolons that separate the sections.

```
for( ; i<10; i++)
{
  // do something
}
```

The [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) are not very clear about this. They say

> The for statement defines *initializer, condition, and iterator
>   sections*: All three sections are optional.

But there is no example on how to skip only the initializer section. However there is an example that gives you an hint when they explain how to write an infinite loop

```
for ( ; ; )
{
    // Body of the loop.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, took a quick search for that and couldn't find it.